# VBA Range.Find to identify all the words "Date" and store its position

Tags: excel, vba

I was hoping to get some help from this community.

I need to program a code that searches among the first row the word "Date" in different cells. I want it to find every cell and tell me its column position, so that later I can ask it to format these columns with a short-data.

Thanks a lot!

Luis

Here is the code provided by Gary's Student that solved everything.

Sub DateFinder()
    Dim msg As String
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Range("1:1"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)

```
For Each cell In rng
    If InStr(cell.Value, "Date") > 0 Then
        msg = msg & vbCrLf & cell.Column
    End If
Next cell
MsgBox msg
```

End Sub

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with the code you've tried so far?

Comment: Hey @BigBen! Thanks for taking a look. I have not programmed anything yet. I don't even know where to start, so I needed ideas before deep diving into it.

Comment: Unfortunately this site is geared at specific questions about existing code, and not for broader questions like that.

Comment: Do some research into the `Find` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub DateFinder()
    Dim msg As String
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Range("1:1"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)

    For Each cell In rng
        If InStr(cell.Value, "Date") > 0 Then
            msg = msg & vbCrLf & cell.Column
        End If
    Next cell
    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Gary's Student, the code worked beautifully. I just changed the worksheet in which I wanted it to look for those "Date". Let me tell you that the solution was pretty ingenious and totally love! I just voted for the answer, hope it is useful! I really appreciate it, you are the best.

Answer (score -1):

### Apply Formatting to Specific Columns

Adjust the values in the constants section appropriately.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChangeFormat()

' Variables

    Const SheetName As String = "Sheet1"  ' Worksheet Name
    Const SearchRow As Long = 1           ' Search Row
    Const FirstColumn As Long = 1         ' First Column
    Const Criteria As String = "Date"     ' Criteria

    Dim ws As Worksheet         ' Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range            ' Last Cell in Row, Search Range,
                                ' Last Cell in Column, First Cell of
                                ' Formatting Range, Formatting Range
    Dim cel As Range            ' Current Cell
    Dim ColumnsArray() As Long  ' Columns Array
    Dim NumberOfRows As Long    ' Number of Rows (to be formatted)
    Dim i As Long               ' Columns Array Elements (Columns) Counter

' Program

    ' Define Worksheet.
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName)

    ' Define Search Range.

    ' Find Last Cell in Row i.e. the right-most cell in Search Row
    ' containing data.
    Set rng = ws.Rows(SearchRow) _
      .Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    ' Define Search Range.
    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(SearchRow, FirstColumn), rng)

    ' Collect Columns.

    ' Loop through cells in Search Range.
    For Each cel In rng
        ' Check if value of Current Cell is equal to Criteria.
        If cel.Value = Criteria Then
            GoSub CollectColumns
        End If
    Next cel
    ' Check if no cells with Criteria have been found.
    If i = 0 Then GoTo NothingFound

    ' Define Formatting Range.

    ' Define Last Cell in Column i.e. the bottom-most cell
    ' in its column containing data.
    Set rng = ws.Columns(ColumnsArray(0)) _
      .Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    ' Calculate the number of rows to be formatted.
    NumberOfRows = rng.Row - SearchRow ' (not adding Search Row)
    ' Define first column of Formatting Range.
    Set rng = ws.Cells(SearchRow + 1, ColumnsArray(0)).Resize(NumberOfRows)
    ' 'Add' the rest of the columns of Formatting Range using 'Union'.
    For i = 1 To UBound(ColumnsArray)
        Set rng = Union(rng, ws.Cells(SearchRow + 1, ColumnsArray(i)) _
          .Resize(NumberOfRows))
    Next i

    ' Apply formatting to Formatting Range.
    With rng
        .NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"  ' depending on your locale maybe "d.m.yyyy"
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End With

    ' Inform User.
    MsgBox "Formatting finished successfully.", vbInformation

GoTo exitProcedure

' Subroutines

CollectColumns:
    ReDim Preserve ColumnsArray(i)
    ColumnsArray(i) = cel.Column
    i = i + 1
Return

' Labels

NothingFound:
    MsgBox "There were no cells containing '" & Criteria & "' in row '" _
      & SearchRow & "'.", vbExclamation
    GoTo exitProcedure

exitProcedure:

End Sub
```

**My Most Important Lesson Acquired**

It seems that you cannot use `Resize` with any kind of non-contiguous range including a range with one column or one row, but you can use `Offset` with it. ( My first plan was to collect the cells and then apply `Offset` and `Resize` on that range.)